# react-native-sqlite-storage cannot open database

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, samsung-galaxy

Every device we test SQLite.openDatabase on works fine except galaxy s10. I have tried every possible combination I can think of and it always just returns failed to open database. Any ideas on how to debug this? These are only a small subset of what I tried

```
SQLite.openDatabase(
    {
         name: 'my_db.db',
         createFromLocation: 1,
    },
    
    () => { 
        console.log("OPEN DATABASE SUCCESS : ")
    },
    error => {
        console.log("OPEN DATABASE ERROR : " + error);
    }
);
```

in place of the 2 we tried 1, 3, 4, default, library, databases, /data/data/<app_name>/my_db.db  data/data/<app_name>/my_db.sqlite

also tried in the formats like

```
 SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'test.db', createFromLocation : path, location: 1}, this.openCB, this.errorCB);
SQLite.openDatabase("test.db", "1.0", "Test Database", 200000, this.openCB, this.errorCB);
```

the path was tried with ~/test.db also with

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/my_db.db';
```

And about 100 more things from every corner of the internet we could find. It should also be noted that
RNFS.writeFile(path, ''); works totally fine. Again works on every device and emulator except galaxy s10. What stupid thing am I missing?

EDIT:
I did an output off all the react native fs locations. /data/data wasn't an options. Which is supposed to be the correct version?

```
 LOG  CachesDirectoryPath /data/user/0/com.<app_name>/cache
 LOG  DocumentDirectoryPath /data/user/0/com.<app_name>/files
 LOG  DownloadDirectoryPath /storage/emulated/0/Download
 LOG  ExternalCachesDirectoryPath /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.<app_name>/cache
 LOG  ExternalDirectoryPath /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.<app_name>/files
 LOG  ExternalStorageDirectoryPath /storage/emulated/0
 LOG  FileProtectionKeys undefined
 LOG  LibraryDirectoryPath undefined
 LOG  MainBundlePath undefined
 LOG  PicturesDirectoryPath /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
 LOG  TemporaryDirectoryPath /data/user/0/com.<app_name>/cache
```

Edit2:
I added code to first create a databases folder, then if successful try touching the database file, byt writing a file with an empty string. All of which were successfuly. But the sqlite open still fails.

```
RNFS.mkdir(DirectoryPath).then((result) => {
  console.log('Wrote folder!', result);     
  const dvfile = 'my_db.db';
  console.log("Final db location = "+DirectoryPath+dvfile);
  RNFS.writeFile(DirectoryPath+dvfile, "").then((result) => {
     console.log("Was able to touch db file!?\n");
      SQLite.openDatabase({name: dvfile, createFromLocation : DirectoryPath+dvfile, location: DirectoryPath+dvfile}, this.openCB, this.errorCB);
  }).catch((err) => {
     console.warn('Failed to touch the db file', err)
  })
            
}).catch((err) => {
    console.warn('Failed to write folder', err)
 })
```

Comment: Try `/data/data/<app_name>/databases/my_db.db` note that you should probably make sure that the **databases** folder exists and if not to make the directory (I think later versions of Android now include/make the directory by default)

Comment: I wasn't able to write to the folder you provided. I realized that the folder path was /data/data/com.<app_name>/databases/my_db.db, the com, isn't in the app name, so maybe this is causing the problem for sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

Try `const db = SQLite.openDatabase('db.db');` with `db.db` in the same directory. Then, try to execute a small sql cmd.

```
 db.transction(
   (tx) => tx.executeSql("create table name;"),
   (e) => console.error(e),
   () => console.log("success")
 );
```

Comment: hmm I get " ERROR  [Error: Invalid database handle]" on the transaction... What do you mean by "with db.db in the same directory" ? do i first need to create the db.db file ?

Comment: Yes. You need to create a 'db.db' and 'utils.js' in the same directory. Then, open the database as above mention from utils.js.